# Могут ли уже созданные итераторы std::string “сдохнуть” при реалакации памяти в контейнере?

Tags: c++, stl, c++17, итераторы

Я получаю большое количество строк извне и складываю их в один std::string. Потом мне эти строки необходимо восстановить, поэтому после каждой записи я планирую сохранять итератор или индекс где заканчивается запись. Если я уже сохранил N-ое количество итераторов и произошла реалокация памяти внутри строки (например, при вызове метода append) останутся ли эти итераторы валидными?

Например так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
int main() {
  using std::cout;
  using std::endl;
  using std::string;
  using std::vector;

  string str{};
  vector<string::iterator> ends_of_notes{};

  while (true) {
    string tmp{};
    std::cin >> tmp;
    if (tmp == "exit") {
      break;
    }
    str.append(tmp);
    ends_of_notes.push_back(str.end());
  }
  cout << endl << "--------------" << endl;
  string::iterator last_it{str.begin()};
  for (auto c : ends_of_notes) {
    cout << string(last_it, c) << endl;
    last_it = c;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Нет. Вы же сами пишете - произойдет релокация, перенос в иное место...

Comment: @Harry Ну может там под капотом у итераторов не прямое обращение к памяти а что-нибудь натипа begin() + N? Я про это и спрашиваю.

Comment: А почитать документацию?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Они сдохнут при релокации памяти в объекте string, к которому они относятся, то бишь при каждом `str.append(tmp);`. Вместо итераторов сохраняйте смещения относительно начала:

```
string str{};
vector<string::size_type> ends_of_notes{};

for(;;)
{
    string tmp{};
    std::cin >> tmp;
    if (tmp == "exit")
    {
        break;
    }
    str.append(tmp);
    ends_of_notes.emplace_back(str.size());
}
cout << endl << "--------------" << endl;
string::size_type begin_offset{0};
for (auto const & end_offset : ends_of_notes)
{
    cout << string{str.begin() + begin_offset, str.begin() + end_offset} << endl;
    begin_offset = end_offset;
}
```